# How to get DNS name in load balancing environment?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, dns, .net-3.0

I have 4 servers participating in load balancing environment. The same ASP.NET application is being hosted in each server.
I would like to get the DNS Name regardless of the underlying server.
Which one of the followings will give the correct answer?

```
Request.Url.Host
Environment.MachineName
System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
```

Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: You want the DNS name of what? Of each machine? The load balancer? The client?

Comment: I think I used the wrong jargon. I want to have FQDN of the application. For instance, www.myportal.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)`. So for example if the request url is `http://www.contoso.com/index.htm?date=today` this will return `http://www.contoso.com`.

Comment: +1. Note that you still may get wrong result if you accessing your site by server's name like `http://myserver044/mySite/myPage` instead of `http://www.myportal.com/mySite/myPage`. Depending on your needs it may be better to just porovide that name in configuration (i.e. to refuse requests from wrong Urls that happen to point to the same server).

Comment: @Darin - If a load balancer with address `www.domain.com` forwards the request to say `A.domain.com` and `B.domain.com`, will getting the `Request.Url.GetLeftPart` dive `www.domain.com` or currently executing server's urls?

Comment: According to http://www.rajeeshcv.com/post/details/40/stay-away-from-request-url, if you are load balancing, you can get executing server's url

Answer (score 0):

The first. It actually is the ONLY one that is even vaguely relevant.

- Environment.MachineName may be whatever you want - noone says that has to be exposed via DNS. Espeically in a hosting environment.
- System.Net.Dns.GetHostName - will return the host name of the machine, no idea how.

Anyhjoe, both my not be what is used to access the machine. THis is pretty much the Url.Host part only, as this came throug hthe request.